# Como chamar variável alterável de uma activity para um viewModel?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, kotlin, viewmodel

Estou tentando chamar uma variável essencial que utilizei na activity (valid) em uma viewModel, mas não estou conseguindo. Como consigo isso?
Exemplo de como eu preciso:

Activity

```
class Teste : AbstractActivity (){

   var valid : Boolean = false

   fun setReturnValidator(){
   //defino os validadores aqui
      if(.............){
      valid = true
   }

}
```

Onde eu preciso colocar na ViewModel:

```
class Resultado(application : Aplication) : ViewModel(application){

   fun search(int: Int, string: String)
   //Chama aquela variável aqui
      if(valid == true){
      ........
     } else {
      ........
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendo em vista que o que você precisa é usar o valor da variável "valid" em uma função dentro da viewModel.

Pode ser feito de algumas maneiras, dentre elas as duas:

1- Caso a função search seja chamada da Activity(view) que contem a variável "valid", pode passar o valor dela como parâmetro da função:

```
fun search(int: Int, string: String, valid: Boolean)
  if(valid == true){
  ........
 } else {
  ........
 }
```

2- Criar uma variável "isValid" dentro da viewModel e atualizar

```
class Teste : AbstractActivity (){
private lateinit var viewModel: Resultado

var valid : Boolean = false
fun setReturnValidator(){
    //mantendo a estrutura apresentada
    if(condition == true){
        valid = true
        viewModel.isValid = valid
    }
    // ou pode simplesmente atribuir a condição do if diretamente a variável
    viewModel.isValid = condition ?: false
    }
}



class Resultado() : ViewModel() {
    //define uma variável que será usada para armazenar o resultado da operação
    var isValid: Boolean = false

    fun search(int: Int, string: String) {
        if (isValid) {
            // logica caso seja válido
        } else {
       ........
        }
    }
```

Fazemos o que precisamos com o código, mas algumas coisas podem resolver um problema e criar outros.

No caso da ViewModel não é recomendado que ela tenha referencias da Activity, contexto e afins por gerar vazamento de memoria.

Um bom exemplo disso é quando rotacionamos o celular, a view(Activty) é destruída (tela em pé) e recriada (tela deitada) mas sua viewModel sobrevive ao processo.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel